# It exists in VB. net a function analogous to CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, sha256

I wanted to know if there exists in Visul Basic .net Framework 4.8 a library equal to CryptoJS of JavaScript hashing.

Comment: Yes, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link could help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256cryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8

I never used it, but I know there is something existing, so I cannot help more than providing the link.